# Multi-tenant Virtual Host Settings for Apache

Tags: laravel, apache, virtualhost, multi-tenant

I'm new to this multi-tenant world. I'm building a multi-tenant application using Laravel on my local machine (I'm using MAC OS and apache 2.4). I want many sites can be created on the fly. I'm using [Hyn's multi-tenant package](https://medium.com/@ashokgelal/a-full-featured-multi-tenant-app-with-laravel-part-1-4049a3cc229d) for this. Laravel things seems to be setup correctly but when I hit http://mysite1.mydomain.local it gives me error

```
This site can’t be reached mysite1.mydomain.local’s server IP address could not be found.
```

I have tried many combinations for virtual host settings.

My httpd-vhosts.conf file

```
#    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
#    DocumentRoot "/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
#    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
#    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
#    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
#</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/onboardera/public"
    ServerName onboardera.local
    ServerAlias onboardera.local
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/multi-site/"
    ServerName mydomain.local
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.local
</VirtualHost>
```

Hosts file content

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       *.mydomain.local
127.0.0.1       onboardera.local
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

I've been searching google for half a day but no luck.

Comment: Always put your complet domain: mysite1.mydomain.local, mysite2.mydomain.local, ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the hosts file is that it does not support wildcards. You have to specify all tenant (sub) domains separately in your hosts file for them to be resolved locally. A great solution to this is using Laravel valet which ships with dnsmasq; you can configure (one domain in) dnsmasq to always resolve locally.

And, thanks for using my package; if you have need for more support feel free to join the discord chat ;)